# Regular Expressions statement for incoming file

Tags: python, regular-language

I'm really new to both Python and regular expressions, but I am having to use them for my internship. I am reading in a file and using Regular Expressions to pick out the important stuff from the file.

In particular I am having trouble with one line. In the file it looks like this:

```
  TOWNHOME_PTS_COST                price_per_household_lin_this_x
```

I want to have the second string in the line, but the mix of letters and underscores is making it hard for me to code it. I have tried running the following, but it doesn't seem to be working. Additionally, I have been using the `.group(1)` function to pull the contents from other files, but for this line it does not seem to be working, it just returns a blank; I'm pretty sure these two issues are related.

```py
import re

myString ="          TOWNHOME_PTS_COST         price_per_household_lin_this_x"
mapName = re.match(r"[\s]*TOWNHOME_PTS_COST[\s]*([a-z]||_)*", myString)
if(mapName):
    print("Found It!")
    print(mapName.group(0))
else:
    print("Not working")
```

Output:

```
Found It!
TOWNHOME_PTS_COST                price
```

I would like to have the entire second string `price_per_household_lin_this_x`, I have also tried doubling up on the `([a-z]||_)*` and placing more `*` inside that statement, but they all return the same thing for the second string `price`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I hope I understood your question correctly. Please check the code below. I think you can find the difference yourself.

Comment: Additionally to @LazyCoder's answer, note that using parentheses "()" indicates a capturing group (i.e. one that can be back referenced.  For your regex, this is unnecessary, and each of the "\s" and "a-z_" sets can be enclosed within square brackets.  It failed because the match in the last group was for [a-z] or "" or _, and there is no null character ("") in the "price_per_household_lin_this_x" part of the string.

Comment: Are you iterating over the lines in the file and *applying* the regex to each line? Does `r"\s+TOWNHOME_PTS_COST\s+(.*)"` work?

Comment: @wwii Yes, I am iterating over the lines in the file and applying the regex to each line, probably not the best way of doing it. Additionally, the solution you have posted works perfectly. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code :

```
import re

myString ="          TOWNHOME_PTS_COST         price_per_household_lin_this_x"
mapName = re.match(r"[\s]*TOWNHOME_PTS_COST[\s]*([a-z_])+", myString)#Notice the ([a-z_])+ 
if(mapName):
    print("Found It!")
    print(mapName.group(0))
else:
    print("Not working")
```

Output :

```
Found It!
          TOWNHOME_PTS_COST         price_per_household_lin_this_x
```

Comment: Attention with the repetition characters: * means "0 or more instances" whereas + means "1 or more".  It doesn't matter for this particular example, but could be important in other cases.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that at least one character would be required in second column to exist. It would matter in this example too and in general. Food for thought.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Here is the updated version that includes numbers in the second string `mapName = re.match(r"[\s]*TOWNHOME_PTS_COST[\s]*[\-a-zA-Z0-9_]+", myString)`